# Lock files in PHP without using flock

Tags: php, block, file-locking

When a user upload a file(users can upload multiple files)

```
exec('nohup php /main/apache2/work/upload/run.php &');
```

I am using `nohup` as the it needs to be executed in the back end.

In my original design `run.php` scans the directory using `scandir` everytime it's executed. Get an exclusive lock `LOCK_EX` on the file using `flock` and use `LOCK_NB` to skip the file if it has a lock and go the next one. If a file has a lock `//Do logic`. The problem is that the server is missing `fcntl()` library and since `flock` uses that library to execute the locking mechanism, `flock` won't work at the moment. It's going to take a month or two to get that installed(I have no control over that).

So my work around for that is have a temporary file lock.txt that acts a lock. If the filename exists in lock.txt skip the file and go to the next one.

```
$dir = "/main/apache2/work/upload/files/";
$files = scandir($dir);
$fileName = "lock.txt";

for($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) 
{   
    if(substr(strrchr($files[$i],'.csv'),-4) == '.csv')
    {           
        if($file_handle = fopen("$fileName", "rb"))
        {
            while(!feof($file_handle))
            {
                $line = fgets($file_handle);
                $line = rtrim($line);
                if($line == "")
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if($files[$i] == $line)
                    {
                        echo "Reading from lock: ".$line."</br>";
                        $i++; //Go to next file
                    }
                }

            }
            fclose($file_handle);
        }

        if($i >= count($files))
        {
            die("$i End of file");
        }

        if($file_handle = fopen("$fileName", "a+"))
        {
            if(is_writable($fileName))
            {               
                $write = fputs($file_handle, "$files[$i]"."\n");
                //Do logic

                //Delete the file name - Stuck here

                fclose($file_handle);
            }

        }

    }
    else
    {
        //Do nothing
    }
}
```

How can I delete the filename from `lock.txt`?

More importantly, is there a better way to lock a file in php without using `flock`?

Comment: Your method for running the backlground process is flawed - see http://symcbean.blogspot.com/2010/02/php-and-long-running-processes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a shared lock database simply moves the locking problem to that file; it doesn't solve it.

A much better solution is to use one lock file per real file. If you want to lock access to `myFile.csv` then you check `file_exists('myFile.csv.lock')` and `touch('myFile.csv.lock')` if it doesn't exist. And `unlink('myFile.csv.lock')` when done.

Now, there is a possible race-condition between file_exists() and touch(), which can be mitigated by storing the PID in the file and checking if `getmypid()` is indeed the process holding the lock.